# Prove $f(a)-f(b)=n(a-b)$ and what is $n$?

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I think that the following formula is true if $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $\pm n=0,1,2,3,\dots$.

> $$f(a)-f(b)=n(a-b)\tag1$$

I start off noting that it reminds me of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but that is not how I arrived at this formula.

I started with $$\frac{f(a)}{a-b}=?$$

Unfortunately, I wasn't quite sure what the result would be.  However, if we let $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ be polynomials, the result would be something along the lines of

$$\frac{f(a)}{a-b}=g(a,b)+\frac{h(b)}{a-b}$$

In particular, I sought to have $$f(a)\equiv h(b)\pmod{a-b}$$

Through some trial and error, I arrived at the conclusion $f(x)=h(x)$, though I am a bit unsure if this is correct.

From that, I concluded

> $$f(a)-f(b)\equiv0\pmod{a-b}\implies f(a)-f(b)=n(a-b)$$

From this, I also conclude that somehow, $g(a,b)=n(a-b)$, however, I expected $g(a)$ to be a polynomial with a degree one less than $f(a)$.

Looking back at the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, this implies $\int_b^af'(a)da=n(a-b)$.

My questions are a) is my formula $(1)$ is correct, b) what is $n$ as a function of $a,b$, and c) what is $g(a,b)$?

**EDIT**

As K.Power has shown, it fails to work sometimes.  From this I assume it only works if $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  And with a bit more thinking, the coefficients $a_i$ in the polynomial $f(x)$ must have $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Your formula $(1)$ looks like a variation of the Mean Value Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$; then $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^mc_kx^k$ with $c_k$ some coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, therefore$$f(a)-f(b)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^mc_k(a^k-b^k)$$.

Secondly, let $n_k(a,b)$ be defined as follows (for $k\geq1$)
$$n_k(a,b)=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}b^{k-1-i}a^i$$
Since $a^k=(a-b)\cdot n_k(a,b)+b^k$, $a^k\equiv b^k$ (mod $a-b$) holds. This implies
$$f(a)-f(b)=n(a,b)\cdot(a-b)$$
where
$$n(a,b)=\sum_{k=1}^mc_kn_k(a,b)$$

Comment: I lost you at

> Since $a^k=(a-b)\dots$

Comment: It is derived dividing $x^k$ by $x-b$, which leads to $x^k=(x-b)(x^{k-1}+bx^{k-2}+\ldots+b^{k-2}x+b^{k-1})+b^k$. For example, take $k=3$, you can check that $x^3=(x-b)(x^2+bx+b^2)+b^3$; take $x=a$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=0$. Then $$f(a)-f(b)=2-0=2$$ But then $$n(a-b)=\sqrt{2} n\neq 2 \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

So the claim is demonstrably false unless there are added restrictions.

Comment: How about $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: That seems like a possibility. No obvious falsification springs to mind then.

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot about certain restrictions modular arithmetic has.